# Match two columns in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two columns as below

```
Column 1    Column 2
A             B
B             A
C             D
```

I need to create a calculated field that would check if the value in Column 2 exists in Column 1, if it does then return “yes”. (Without blending or duplicating the data)
How do I do it in tableau?

I would appreciate any help can get on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was also asked on the Tableau forums at http://community.tableau.com/thread/170673 and several answers provided there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could potentially create a "**Set**" based off of Column 2, call it **Column 2(Set)** and use the "IN" Operator to create a calculated field like:

```
IF [Column 1] IN [Column 2 (Set)] THEN "Yes" ELSE "No" END
```